# How do I use different datasources for kendo UI grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm not too familiar with Kendo and have watched some tutorials but even following exactly I do not get the same result. I made a page using cached data and pass it as a datasource to the grid in different ways.

In this code, the read method is not being called at all. I have no idea why.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TestCategory>().Name("TCategory1").Columns(c =>
    {
    c.Bound(p => p.Name);
    c.Bound(p => p.Id);
    })
        .DataSource(d => d.Ajax().Read(r => r.Action("Read", "Category").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
        .PageSize(3))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
    )
```

In the second grid, I am able to get the data to display but not able to edit

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("TCategory").Columns(c =>
    {
    c.Bound(p => p.Name);
    c.Bound(p => p.Id);
        c.Command(com => { com.Edit(); com.Destroy(); });
    })
        .DataSource(d => d.Ajax().ServerOperation(false).PageSize(3)
        .Update(u => u.Action("Edit", "Category"))
        .Create(c => c.Action("Create", "Category"))
        .Destroy(c => c.Action("Delete", "Category"))
        .Model(m => { m.Id(p => p.Id); })
        )
        .Pageable().Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)).Sortable().Filterable().ToolBar(t => t.Create()) )
```

Read method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IQueryable<TestCategory> cat = context.Collection();


        return Json(cat.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Did you see the demos on https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid ? There are samples in all flavors.

Comment: Please provide controller code for action method ("Read", "Category").

Comment: Have added the code

Comment: Remove `.Type(HttpVerbs.Get)` -- your method is marked `HttpPost`. Then tell us if there are any console errors.

Comment: There are no errors but I am still unable to get the data to display on the first grid after removing it

Comment: If you are not hitting the Read action, I would look at routing issues.